# RStudio error in windows: Running pdflatex.exe on file_name.tex.. (exit code -1073740791)

Tags: r, windows-10, latex, rstudio, pdflatex

I am using Rstudio in windows 10. I am triying to create a pdf from a .tex file. However, when I compile the PDF, the following error appears:

```
Running pdflatex.exe on file_name.tex...failed Error running C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe (exit code -1073740791)
```

I am using a native installation of R, Rstudio and MikTeX. Not an envioronment with anaconda or similar.

Comment: Might be related to this bug: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/9019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using RStudio, have you tried tinytex instead of MikTeX? In the Tools Menu>Global Options>Sweave, tick "use tinytex for compiling .tex files". Then install tinytex package. After installing tinytex package, write in console "tinytex::install_tinytex()". This will install the latex compiler tinytex. Try compiling your tex file using it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that issue has to do with missing packages. In fact, MiKTeX doesnt preinstall most of them. I recommend to compile with TinyTeX, because it shows where the compilation stops (as I said, due to a missing package typically required in some sty file). This way you can track which are the missing packages and install them on the MiKTeX Console one by one.

I posted about this issue in an open discussion on Github. Drop the link [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/9019#issuecomment-1107906668) in case you need more details.